# Вывести клавиатуру в android в sdl2

Tags: android, sdl2

Например я хочу ввести текст с android в игре с библиотекой sdl2. Есть ли такая функция в sdl2, которая вызывает клавиатуру android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SDL_StartTextInput`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_StartTextInput) должна сработать.

> On some platforms using this function activates the screen keyboard.